# React router to separate page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Very new to react, I'm trying to separate the landingpage, login/signup and the app in react router but I cant to make it work, the page always loads the layout of the landing page and under it the login.

```
// Imports
import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router, Route
} from 'react-router-dom';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

// Data
import Landing from "./components/landing/landing";
import login from './components/app/auth/login';

// App
const Root = () => (
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={Landing} />
        <Route path="/login" component={login} />
    </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(
    <Root />,
    document.querySelector("#root")
)

// Service worker
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `exact path` within the  component. It will look like `<Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />`

The same goes for the login page.

Comment: No worries.  Use just path when routing components like navbars and footers so they load on various pages.